Exterior Differential System Representation for Wave Equation in Three Spatial Dimensions
Is there any resource that shows the wave equation in three spatial dimensions (without any symmetry/constraint imposed on the system) is not a Pfaffian system due to the fact that the differential ideal, that its EDS is associated with, is composed of p-forms of tensor rank higher than one?

Clarification: Any PDE or system of PDEs can be written as a Pfaffian system. The question presumably is whether this PDE can be written as an exterior differential system that is not a Pfaffian system. Is that right?

@Deane, Yes exactly! Otherwise, I know that any contact system is Pfaffian; but my question is when that system is restricted to the wave equation in three spatial dimensions, because its differential ideal cannot be simply-generated anymore (at least I heard of). However, I couldn’t find any resource that explains it thoroughly. They either impose a radial symmetry or put it in an Euler-Lagrangian framework. I just want pure EDS for pure wave equation in three spatial dimensions.

The standard way to write
$$
u_{00} - u_{11}-u_{22}-u_{33} = 0,
$$
as an exterior differential system is to set
$$ X = \{ (x^j,u,p_k,q_{jk}):\ 0 \le j,k\le 3,\ q_{jk}=q_{kj},\ (q_{00})^2 - (q_{11})^2-(q_{22})^2-(q_{33})^2 = 0 \} $$
with the following Pfaffian system:
\begin{align*}
dx^0\wedge dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3 &\ne 0\\
du - p_j\,dx^j &= 0\\
dp_j - q_{jk}\,dx^k &= 0
\end{align*}
If you don't want a Pfaffian system, I believe the following works: Let $$ Y = \{ (x^j,u, p_k):\ 0 \le j,k \le 3 \} $$
with the following exterior differential system:
\begin{align*}
dx^0\wedge dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3 &\ne 0\\
du - p_j\,dx^j &= 0\\
dp_0\wedge dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3 + dp_1\wedge dx^0\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3 &\\
- dp_2\wedge dx^0\wedge dx^1\wedge dx^3 + dp_3\wedge dx^0\wedge dx^1\wedge dx^2 &= 0
\end{align*}

Prof. @Deane, what is that constraint on the second order terms: $(q_{00})^2= (q_{11})^2+(q_{22})^2+(q_{33})^2$? Another problem with the first translation of DE system into EDS: Let $\mathcal{I}\vert_{\Sigma^{(2)}}={\omega_1, \omega_2}$, where $\Sigma^{(2)}$ is the submanifold describing the wave eqn in $J^{(2)}$, $\omega_1=du-\sum_j p_j dx^j$, $\omega_2=dp_0-(\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial p_i}{\partial x^i})dx^0$, and $p_j=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^j},, j=0,1,2,3$. Thus, $d\omega_2 \not\in \mathcal{I}\vert_{\Sigma^{(2)}}$. What am I missing?

As far as I can tell, $\omega^2$ does not appear in my system. The constraint is the wave equation
